# Why inclusion of external Rmd-file with latex equation environment leads to different DOCX output while using rmarkdown and bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, docx, bookdown

Below is the simplest Rmd file which I'm knitting to MS Word document using latest RStudio:

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
  bookdown::word_document2: default
---

```{sh, echo=FALSE, comment=''}
cat ~/latex-test.Rmd
```
````

The contents of `~/latex-test.Rmd` are as follows:

```
Auto-numbered equation:

$$ f(x) = \sin(x) $$ 

---

LaTeX equation without label (using `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`)

\begin{equation}
h(z) = \sinh(z)
\end{equation}

---

LaTeX equation with bookdown-supported label (using `\begin{equation}...(\#eq:label)\end{equation}`)

\begin{equation}
  f\left(k\right) = \binom{n}{k} p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}
  (\#eq:binom)
\end{equation}

---

LaTeX equation with Xaringan-supported label (using `\begin{equation}...\label{label}\end{equation}`):

\begin{equation}
  g\left(k\right) = \binom{n}{k} p^k\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}
\label{binom2}
\end{equation}
```

Knitting to `word_document: default` gives exactly the same contents of docx file as contained in `~/latex-test.Rmd`.
So I will not include it here to save the space.

But knitting to `bookdown::word_document2: default` gives extra `$$...$$` which surround `equation` environments:

[image: bookdown docx output]

(I have highlighted the unexpected `$$` manually)

Why this happening? What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

---

Notes:

1. the outputs of `html_document: default` and `bookdown::html_document2: default` are equal and correct.
2. the outputs of `odt_document: default` and `bookdown::odt_document2: default` are incorrect too.

Comment: Sounds like a **bookdown** bug (not smart enough to know that these equations are inside a verbatim code block).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in **bookdown** that [I just fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/commit/985f0199f11f70b7d9ab362c615f251f9b108a84) on Github. You may try the development version of **bookdown** via `remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')`.